# How to enable a crate feature dynamically?

Tags: build, rust, rust-cargo

I've got a crate that can be compiled with or without a feature, let's say `feat_crate`.

I use that crate from a program that can also be compiled with or without a feature `feat_app`.

I'd like to enable `feat_crate` for the dependency whenever `feat_app` is enabled; `feat_app` being enabled when building the app (like in *`cargo run  -- --feat_app`* ⚠ EDIT, like in **`cargo run --features feat_app`**).

I cannot find a simple way to do so without modifying the `Cargo.toml` file each time I want to change the enabled feature. I tried looking at build scripts but the script for the app is executed after the dependencies are compiled, so it doesn't seem to help.

I probably can use an environment variable fetched from the crate build script, meaning I would have to set that environment variable accordingly... but I was hoping for a better solution.

Comment: _"feat_app being enabled when building the app (like in `cargo run -- --feat_app`)."_ Is it part of the requirement to compile the program differently based on that `--feat_app` option? This one is never really passed into the compiler.

Comment: They probably mean `--features feat_app`? The text description doesn't really make sense otherwise.

Comment: You are right, I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the features documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features.html):

> Features can be used to reexport features of other packages. The `session` feature of package `awesome` (nb: that's the "current" package) will ensure that the `session` feature of the package `cookie` is also enabled.
>
> ```
> session = ["cookie/session"]
> ```

Comment: Thanks! 
I wondered how such a feature wouldn't be already implemented...