# Enable chrono feature with r2d2_postgres crate

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm learning Rust, and I can't seem to use the `FromSql` trait from the `r2d2_postgres` crate.

Based on [this recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64856538/how-to-enable-a-crate-feature-dynamically), I tried adding the feature in my TOML file:

```
r2d2_postgres = {version = "0.18", features = ["postgres/with-chrono-0_4"]}
```

But then Rust tells me:

```
feature `postgres/with-chrono-0_4` in dependency `r2d2_postgres` is not allowed to contain slashes
If you want to enable features of a transitive dependency, the direct dependency needs to re-export those features from the `[features]` table.
```

Comment: Technically, this is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59994525/how-do-i-specify-features-for-a-sub-dependency-in-cargo) already, but the answer isn't very good. In any case, [r2d2_postgres has no features](https://docs.rs/crate/r2d2_postgres/0.18.1/source/Cargo.toml.orig) so you can't specify feature flags on that. You'll have to specify `postgres` as a dependency and add the feature flag there.

Comment: Thanks to your answer, I've found a workaround for r2d2. I couldn't get the `postgres` crate to work with data coming from `r2d2_postgres`, so I ended up borrowing the algorithms from https://github.com/sfackler/rust-postgres/blob/master/postgres-types/src/chrono_04.rs

Comment: If you can't get the two to work together, you may have pulled in two different versions of `postgres`. Check `cargo tree --duplicates`.

Comment: Using that command, I saw that crate `r2d2_postgres` version 0.18 uses `postgres` 0.19, while I also imported `postgres` 0.18 in my TOML file. Even the compiler complained to me about it: *"expected struct `postgres::types::Type`, found struct `r2d2_postgres::postgres::types::Type`"* and *"perhaps two different versions of crate `postgres_types` are being used?"*. Funny..

Comment: You might want to depend on `postres = ">= 0"` or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to work with both `r2d2` and `chrono`, an extra dependency on the `postgres` crate is needed. But the `postgres` crate must be the same version as the `r2d2_postgres::postgress` crate in order to work together.

Versions can be compared with the output of `cargo tree --duplicates`.

At this time of writing, `Cargo.toml` must contain:

```
[dependencies]
r2d2_postgres = "0.18"
postgres = {version = "0.19", features = ["with-chrono-0_4"]}
```

Thank you [Caesar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/401059/caesar).